# Google+ photos api

Tags: api, gdata, gdata-api, google-plus, photos

Is there a Google+ photos gdata API? I was using [Google picasa API](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html) but picasa has a 1 GB limit for photos. I want to upload all my photos using the script which i am [writing](https://github.com/devsundar/whoopee/blob/master/toys/photomanager/photoman.py) to Google+ photos.

Is there a Google+ photos gdata API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google+ does not currently have a public photo API. It was [accidentally announced](http://thenextweb.com/google/2011/11/16/google-accidentally-announces-google-photo-and-video-apis-too-early/) at one point but has not been officially announced since.

If 1GB is not enough you can [pay to increase it](http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=39567).

Answer (score 2):

Picasa has a 1GB limit for photos greater than 2048 x 2048 pixels. However, there is no limit to photos which are uploaded under this size limitation.

On the other hand, you can use the [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/about-sdk) SDK to upload your photos. The free usable limit on Google Drive is currently 5GB.