# solution for uploading to google+

Tags: php, node.js, google-api, google-plus

Im working in a project in which I want to give users the opportunity to post images in google +
then I try in a first step to use google api, but unfortunately no results.
so what's the best solution to resolve this problem??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google+ photos api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782651/google-photos-api)

Comment: even with the node.js ??

Comment: Read the [doc!](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/): it's writen "The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key." Even with node.js, or whatever techno you want